# Delphi XE - Delphi Project Using Qt GUI Library

Tags: qt, delphi, user-interface, stylesheet

I have a proyect in Delphi XE3 using VCL application, now I want to improve my application GUI and I want to use a Qt GUI Widget with stylesheets using my existing delphi source code (implemented classes,...) , it's this possible?. I has been search on Net but nothing founded about implementing Qt GUI for Delphi.
Thx in advanced.

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  Delphi being a Turing-complete language, anything is possible if it's possible anywhere else.  Is it a good idea?  That's another question.  Delphi tried going the Qt route several years ago, and it was a miserable failure.

Comment: @David, if you want to improve the visual appearance of your application then you could be using Delphi Native VCL Styles.

Comment: It's a moot point whether or not VCL styles improve appearance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what's your beef with VCL Styles, please share, I want to know xD

Comment: @PeterVonča It's a bug factory. Even in XE4 I expect there are still loads of bugs. As an aside I think that most of the styled apps that I have seen look revolting.

Comment: @PeterVonča , Problem with VCL Styles it's that are limited and as DavidHeffernan says i cant see any good look aplication yet with they.

Comment: @MasonWheeler , Any idea or document to read anything about how do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, In XE2 it was a total wreck but a lot has changed since then. I actually use it quite a lot this days and while I agree that there's still numerous bugs all around, when I weigh in on the pros and cons I'll always go with VCL Styles because it's turned out to be a very fast, powerful and easy Delphi native method to change the appearance. Regarding the looks, that could be because most of the included styles are pretty bad design wise, few are decent. When you actually go for your own design you start to realize the full potential and ease of use, of the VCL Styles.

Comment: any hint about my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no Delphi bindings for Qt:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_bindings_for_Qt_4

Delphi is inextricably bound to either the VCL or Firemonkey. Without no bindings available, you can't directly use Qt in Delphi.

A possible workaround could be to abstract your application routines into a DLL and then create the GUI for your application in another language with Qt support and call your Delphi routines from that.

Also @ Mason:

> Delphi tried going the Qt route several years ago, and it was a miserable failure

The failure of Kylix had nothing to do with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the last version of codetyphon 5.30
http://pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php
VLC is support with Multi-OS, Multi-CPU and Cross-Build abilities.
especially with QT4 binding platform support 
QT5 platform support is Experimental.